# Angular - Router Config - redirectTo using parameters/variable segment

Tags: angular, router

In the example routing configuration below, I'm receiving a Error: Cannot redirect to '/ip/:id'. Cannot find ':id' when entering localhost:8080\sso\ip\1. I'm trying to understand how to redirect using variable segments of the path. In this case :id cannot seem to be found. I referenced https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-redirects-2826177761fc which describes a similar use case where a dynamic segment is used within a redirectTo property.

Does the id get resolved using the :id parameter from the initiated /sso/ip/**:id** route? A similar question was asked, but never responded to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Mw0N3qYphO8.

Any assistance is much appreciated?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
      path: 'ip',
      children: [
        {
          path: ':id',
          children: [
            {
              path: 'tcv',
              component: IpTcvComponent          
            },
            {
              path: '',
              component: IpComponent          
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: '',
          component: IpHomeComponent          
        }
      ]
  },  
  { 
    path: 'sso',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'ip',
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            children: [
              {
                path: 'tcv',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: '/ip/:id/tcv'
              },
              {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: '/ip/:id'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: '/ip'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to redirect to this route?

Comment: @DeborahK I think it's all there in route configs. When user goes to `/sso/ip/:id`, OP wants to redirect to `/ip/:id` using the same value for `:id` that was provided to the original path. However it seems as though the router tries to look for the literal route `/ip/:id` (without substituting the id value), a route which doesn't exist since `:id` is just a parameter

Comment: I assume there is a routerLink or .navigate() method that is doing this. I was hoping to see that code to see how that process was done. Or maybe  misunderstood ... is the user typing the path into the address bar?

Comment: @BettleJuice, you nailed what I trying to do. The browser is used to perform the routing. I enter localhost:8080/sso/ip/1 and expect to be redirected to localhost:8080/ip/1. Utilizing the Routing Config only, no javascript that engages the Angular Router. I'm in the process of putting together a sample application since my original application is much larger and would distract from the question at hand.

Comment: @DeborahK. Created a Plunker to demonstrate the question. If the SSO IP component link is click the error is written to the console. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nfmB8lnkAkKQipcpl5Nr?p=preview)

Comment: OK, I spoke to one of the guys that knows just about everything about the router. He said that based on this example: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16377 he expected that what you did should work. It looks like a router bug to him. Would you be willing to post the info from here along with the link to your plunker as an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular ?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to handle redirection manually if I can't get the routes config to work. Have a `RedirectService` with a `redirectInFlight()` method that listens to the `Router.events` observable. When the router tries to go to a target path such as `/sso/ip/:id`, transparently redirect to the right path: `/ip/:id`

I would then add the service to `AppModule.providers`, inject the service in `AppComponent`, and call `redirectInFlight()`

**AppComponent**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    //inject the RedirectService
    constructor(private redirectSvc:RedirectService){}

    //start listening to the router and redirecting
    ngOnInit() {this.redirectSvc.redirectInFlight();}
}
```

**RedirectService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; //replace with just the classes you need from RxJS library

@Injectable()
export class RedirectService {
    events$:Observable<any>; //stream of Router events

    constructor(private router:Router) {
        this.events$ =
            //listen to router events and inspect the `url` string property
            //and filter for urls that begin with /sso
            this.router.events.filter(e=> e.url && e.url.startsWith('/sso'))
    }

    redirectInFlight(){
        //First remove /sso from the start of url to fix it
        this.events$.map(e => e.url.replace('/sso',''))
            //navigate to the fixed URL
            .subscribe(newUrl=>this.router.navigateByUrl(newUrl));
    }
}
```

Finally, you can remove the whole `sso` path and its children paths from your router config, simplifying it a great deal.

[**Live demo**](https://embed.plnkr.co/8ncY575bHGikuqVte3jG/)

Note: This implementation is a starting point. You can make it more robust by storing and referring to a map of redirections, instead of hardcoding "/sso".